# history gives me too many subquery results

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, restore

I appreciate your help, I hope I'm able to provide adequate information.

I need to roll back owners associated with quite a few entries in our asset table (one owner got applied to a lot of systems). I have a history table with the information I need, and an employee table that gets wedged in there because for some reason the history table stores names rather than employee_id's.

Source data:
`asset_table` has `asset_id, employee_id, asset_tag`

`employee_table` has `employee_id, name`

`history_table` has `asset_id, old_name, new_name`

```
update asset_table
set employee_id = (select employee_id
                   from employee_table
                   where name like (select old_name
                                    from history_table
                                    where asset_table.asset_id=history_table.asset_id
                                    and new_name like 'tobe replaced'))
```

However, the subquery turns up more than one result per line.

What am I missing to limit that subquery results?

MSSQL server 2012

Comment: Please add some sample source data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write update statement is as below by using JOIN instead of sub query, Provide table structure and data for more correct query:

```
update at set at.employee_id = et.employee_id
from asset_table at
inner join history_table ht on at.asset_id = ht.asset_id
    and ht.new_name like '%tobe replaced%'
inner join employee_table et on et.name = ht.old_name
    and et.employee_id = at.employee_id
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I did remove the  your finial line since it blocked any results, (the assets were assigned to 'tobe replaced').

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need someone who was the last in history:

```
update at set
   employee_id = e.employee_id
from asset_table at
cross apply
(
  select top (1)
         h.old_name
    from history_table h
   where at.asset_id = h.asset_id
     and h.new_name = 'tobe replaced'
   order by h.<date or id or something> desc
) h
inner join employee_table e
   on e.name = h.old_name
```

`TOP 1` will fix "more than one result" problem.

Note, `LIKE` without `%` works exactly the same way as `=`.